# Having trouble with finviz screener tool using Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

Looked over a similar question that involves the same site, but it looks like my problem has different css/html to it. Read through the scrapy tutorial, but still having trouble getting the code to print.

```
import scrapy

class finvizSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "finviz"
    
    start_urls = [
        "https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_small,geo_usa,sh_avgvol_o300,sh_opt_option,sh_short_low&ft=4&o=-change",
        "https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_small,geo_usa,sh_avgvol_o300,sh_opt_option,sh_short_low&ft=4&o=-ticker&r=21",
        "https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_small,geo_usa,sh_avgvol_o300,sh_opt_option,sh_short_low&ft=4&o=-ticker&r=41",
        "https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_small,geo_usa,sh_avgvol_o300,sh_opt_option,sh_short_low&ft=4&o=-ticker&r=61",
        "https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_small,geo_usa,sh_avgvol_o300,sh_opt_option,sh_short_low&ft=4&o=-ticker&r=81",
        "https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_small,geo_usa,sh_avgvol_o300,sh_opt_option,sh_short_low&ft=4&o=-ticker&r=101",
        "https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_small,geo_usa,sh_avgvol_o300,sh_opt_option,sh_short_low&ft=4&o=-ticker&r=121",
        "https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_small,geo_usa,sh_avgvol_o300,sh_opt_option,sh_short_low&ft=4&o=-ticker&r=141",
        "https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_small,geo_usa,sh_avgvol_o300,sh_opt_option,sh_short_low&ft=4&o=-ticker&r=161",
        "https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_small,geo_usa,sh_avgvol_o300,sh_opt_option,sh_short_low&ft=4&o=-ticker&r=181",
        "https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_small,geo_usa,sh_avgvol_o300,sh_opt_option,sh_short_low&ft=4&o=-ticker&r=201"]
    def parse(self, response):
        data = response.xpath('//div[@id="screener-content"]/div/table/tbody').extract()
        print(data)
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

EDIT:

The answer below allows me to run just one url in the scrapy shell and it switches the original url to the main page without the filters added on.

[image]

I am still unable to run this in python. I will attach the output.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Check the solution  below and let me know if you have any difficulty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues in your code:

First, Scrapy response does not contains `<tbody>` elements  because it downloads the original HTML page. While, what you see in the browser is the modified HTML which adds `<tbody>` elements to tables.

Second, you have added an extra `div` element, //div[@id="screener-content"]**/div**/table/tbody (talking about bold one).

Try this XPath, `'//div[@id="screener-content"]/table//tr/td/table//tr/td//text()'` or just execute the below modified code.

**Code**

```
import scrapy

class finvizSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "finviz"

    start_urls = [
        "https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_small,geo_usa,sh_avgvol_o300,sh_opt_option,sh_short_low&ft=4&o=-change",
        "https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_small,geo_usa,sh_avgvol_o300,sh_opt_option,sh_short_low&ft=4&o=-ticker&r=21",
        "https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_small,geo_usa,sh_avgvol_o300,sh_opt_option,sh_short_low&ft=4&o=-ticker&r=41",
        "https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_small,geo_usa,sh_avgvol_o300,sh_opt_option,sh_short_low&ft=4&o=-ticker&r=61",
        "https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_small,geo_usa,sh_avgvol_o300,sh_opt_option,sh_short_low&ft=4&o=-ticker&r=81",
        "https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_small,geo_usa,sh_avgvol_o300,sh_opt_option,sh_short_low&ft=4&o=-ticker&r=101",
        "https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_small,geo_usa,sh_avgvol_o300,sh_opt_option,sh_short_low&ft=4&o=-ticker&r=121",
        "https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_small,geo_usa,sh_avgvol_o300,sh_opt_option,sh_short_low&ft=4&o=-ticker&r=141",
        "https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_small,geo_usa,sh_avgvol_o300,sh_opt_option,sh_short_low&ft=4&o=-ticker&r=161",
        "https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_small,geo_usa,sh_avgvol_o300,sh_opt_option,sh_short_low&ft=4&o=-ticker&r=181",
        "https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_small,geo_usa,sh_avgvol_o300,sh_opt_option,sh_short_low&ft=4&o=-ticker&r=201"]
    def parse(self, response):
        
        tickers = response.xpath('//a[@class="screener-link-primary"]/text()').extract()
        print(tickers)
```

**Output Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Am I supposed to add something else to this? Can't seem to get a list of the stock tickers back.

Comment: @MattFriend, please check the edited code, the printed result will return ticker. Let me know if it works.

Comment: This has been great help. Why does this only print ticker prices though given whats in the xpath?

Comment: @MattFriend Great it worked. Would you mind to accept the answer?  Similarly, you can use XPath for other fields.

Comment: Not sure if its on my side because I am running it in the command prompt, but it seems like the filter isnt going through and it is redirecting me to the main page with all stocks. And then just printing out the first page of stocks.

Comment: For me it's printing the ticker list associated with each url.

Comment: I am unable to get it to work in python spyder. This works in the scrapy shell, for some reason the url is changed to "https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111 in the shell. Is there something wrong with my settings? I am trying to get this to work in spyder. See edits in original post.

Comment: I am not sure how are you running it but looks like the issue is on your side i.e., running script via API (check your error). Try to run via normal scrapy crawl. I have attached the screenshot of output and it's working fine for me using command prompt as well.

Comment: Using this in spyder. Do I need to set a user agent? When I run this code as is nothing happens. I first need to add a crawl. I'm not even sure how I incorporate the finvizspider in my main script. Do I just instantiate and it will automatically start parsing?

Comment: No, without user agent it works. Check, the log of last screenshot that you added it shows the script is not even getting executed and it throws reactor error. It can be  be your local environment issue. Try to run the same code using PyCharm after installing all dependency.